# accessing multiple elements in a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

How can one access a vector of elements from different columns efficiently in matlab
for example:

```
A = [1 2 5 4
     4 6 2 5
     3 6 8 9
     2 4 5 7
     2 9 4 2]
```

retrieve: `(1, 1) (2,2) (3,1) (4,4) (5,3)`

Answer (score 3):

use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
ret = [1 1;
       2 2;
       3 1;
       4 4;
       5 3];

A( sub2ind(size(A), ret(:,1), ret(:,2)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

`sub2ind` is almost definitely the way to go, but if you really need it to be fast, you *might* find it faster to just calculate the linear indices yourself:

```
A = [1 2 5 4
     4 6 2 5
     3 6 8 9
     2 4 5 7
     2 9 4 2]

ret = [1 1;
       2 2;
       3 1;
       4 4;
       5 3];

n = size(A,1)

A(ret(:,1) + (ret(:,2)-1)*n)
```